# I want qt window to resize proportional

Tags: qt, resize, window

Just as the title said, when I resize the window, if I make it widen , I want the window's height resize proportional to make the window has the same ratio.
I just do the logic in paintEvent, but it doesn't work fine, can some guys have any solution?

I don't think do resizing in resizeEvent is a great way, the best result is that window flickering,  but I want the fluent way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it in `paintEvent` but instead `void QWidget::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event )`. Then you can compare `event->size()` and `event->oldsize()` to see which dimension got changed, then resize to match the other dimension to the changed one.

EDIT: Note that when you resize the window inside the resizeEvent function, you will create another resize event. So make sure you only resize if there's been a change that brought the window to a wrong aspect ratio, otherwise you will create infinite recursion to the function and a stack overflow.

Comment: I just did this in resizeEvent. And I think may some of code has bugs.And base on your answer, I think mine thought was applicable, thx!I will try again